# Running Deluge as a non-root user

Tags: deluge

I can't seem to get deluged to run as I feel it should: as a daemon with a non-root user.

I've installed 1.3.3 from the default repo as well as building it from source via this article: http://www.onepitwopi.com/raspberry-pi/installing-deluge-1-3-6-on-a-raspberry-pi/

I created a 'deluge' with a home in /var/lib/deluge.
I tried using the init.d and upstart scripts.
The upstart script never runs as the deluge user even when ensuring that the deluged.conf file uses the deluge user. The init.d script only runs the daemon on localhost even after specifying in the config to allow remote connections.

Does anyone have deluged setup as a non-root user and allow remote connections?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I needed to do.

First I did end up following [this tutorial](http://www.onepitwopi.com/raspberry-pi/installing-deluge-1-3-6-on-a-raspberry-pi/) to install 1.3.11 of deluge.

I then followed the deluge [upstart guides](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart).

The missing key was to install systemd and remove sysvinit.

`sudo apt-get install sysvinit- systemd`

Then restart. Works like a charm.